# Is there anyway to manually restart the webview rendering engine in Android?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a ListView and after clicking the ListView item, I will show a fragment with webview embedded inside to show html contents. However, sometimes I found that webview failed to render the content, and once it failed even I came back to the listview and click other items, they are most likely will fail to render too. I have to restart the app to correctly show the html content.From such behavior, I suspects that the webview rendering engine may fail to render certain contents randomly, I'm thinking if so, I need to restart the rendering engine to reveal the content. Am I on the right track? If so, how can I restart it? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Did u try webView.reload()?

Comment: There are some issues here, how do we know webview failed the render? I could not see anything from logcat. The second concern is the first time it fails, how to guarantee reload will work?